# Twain support in Linux (c++)

Tags: linux, twain

How can I acquire images in linux using TWAIN?

I cannot find any help or sample to start with.
I just need tips to start.

Comment: I do not think the linux port took off in the end. Can you use SANE? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) to acquire images. Read the [SANE - Introduction](http://www.sane-project.org/intro.html), and you can find all relevant resources on its official website.